# Shopify: Is it possible to update the price of a product at checkout in the liquid template?

Tags: shopify

If a buyer purchases an item from a Shopify store, we would like to customise the system such that the buyer can select another product from a specific collection in the same store for free with that purchase i.e. buy a premium dvd and receive another dvd for free (where the free dvd must be choosen from a specific collection).

Any suggestions on how best to achieve this?

Would it be possible to edit (hack) the theme's cart template to set the price to zero for the  second free item added to the cart if it is in the specific "free" collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you iterate through a cart and find a "premium" product in it with no "free" upsell product, you would render the collection "free stuff" for the customer, and they could pick from that collection. The products in the Free collection are indeed free.

And if you render a cart with an item from the Free collection and NO Premium item is in the cart, you probably want to disable checkout.

Would that be "good enough"?

Comment: Thanks David. That definitely sounds like what we are trying to achieve. So, what you suggest, is this possible to do in liquid?

Comment: I would say yes. As you're rendering products, keep track of the state of the Premium and Free ones. As a result, either render the Free collection or disable the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You can create discount codes that can be applied to a single item in a collection.  You can simply set the discount for that item to be 100% off.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I however do not think this will work in our case as we want it to be store wide for all customers and we do not want to have to issue each customer with a discount code. Also, the "buy one get one free" offer needs to be able to be used by each customer an unlimited number of times (but they can only get one free dvd with each individual premium purchase).